# Regression tree with simulated data - rpart package

Tags: r, split, rpart

I have simulated some data to create a regression tree with 3 terminal nodes:

```
set.seed(1988)
n=1000
X1<-rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=2)
X2<-rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=2)
e<-rnorm(n)
Y=5*I(X1<1)*I(X2<0.2)+4*I(X1<1)*I(X2>=0.2)+3*I(X1>=1)+e
mydat=as.data.frame(cbind(Y,X1,X2))
```

So, I want first to split by X1<1, and for X1<1 I want to split by X2<0.2. The values of Y in the leaves are the coefficient of the indicator.

If I run the procedure implemented in the RPART package everything is ok in the case above.

```
mytree<-rpart(Y~.,data=mydat)
mytree
```

Output:

```
node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 1000 1627.0670 4.043696  
  2) X1>=0.9490461 326  373.8485 3.124825 *
  3) X1< 0.9490461 674  844.8367 4.488135  
    6) X2>=0.2488142 327  312.7506 3.970742 *
    7) X2< 0.2488142 347  362.0582 4.975708 *
```

It runs also if I try with coefficient all negative. 
But when I try to generate some negative and some positive values in the final terms (it means in the "interaction" of the tree, so where the split is divided at a second level), RPART change the order of the split and the value in the leaves are not correct:

```
Y=-5*I(X1<1)*I(X2<0.2)+4*I(X1<1)*I(X2>=0.2)+3*I(X1>=1)+e
mydat=as.data.frame(cbind(Y,X1,X2))

mytree<-rpart(Y~.,data=mydat)
mytree
```

Output:

```
  node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 1000 17811.4000  0.6136962  
  2) X2< 0.1974489 515  8116.5350 -2.3192910  
    4) X1< 1.002815 343   359.7394 -5.0305350 *
    5) X1>=1.002815 172   207.4313  3.0874360 *
  3) X2>=0.1974489 485   560.3419  3.7281050 *
```

Anyone have some idea for that problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tune the complexity parameter `cp`. See the code below.

```
# Data Generating Process
set.seed(1988)
n=1000
X1<-rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=2)
X2<-rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=2)
e<-rnorm(n)
Y=-5*I(X1<1)*I(X2<0.2)+4*I(X1<1)*I(X2>=0.2)+3*I(X1>=1)+e
mydat=as.data.frame(cbind(Y,X1,X2))

library(rpart)
mytree<-rpart(Y~.,data=mydat, cp=0.0001)

# Plot the cross-validation error vs the complexity parameter
plotcp(mytree)
```

[image]

```
# Find the optimal value of the complexity parameter cp
optcp <- mytree$cptable[which.min(mytree$cptable[,4]),1]

# Prune the tree using the optial complexity parameter
mytree <- prune(mytree,optcp)
```

The pruned tree correctly represents the underlying data generating process

```
library(rattle)
fancyRpartPlot(mytree)
```

[image]